# Accessing Observable value in Angular 2 component

Tags: angular, observable, behaviorsubject

I need to access current product in addToCart() method.

```
export class ProductComponent implements OnInit {

    private product : Observable<Product>;

     constructor(private activatedRoute : ActivatedRoute,
                 private productService : ProductService,
                 private cartService : CartService) {

          this.product = productService.product;
      }

    private addToCart(qty: HTMLInputElement ,
                    model: HTMLInputElement, 
                    id: HTMLInputElement) : void {

     var orderItemRequest = new OrderItemRequest(Number(id.value),
                                                 model.value,
                                                 Number(qty.value))

     this.cartService.addProduct(orderItemRequest);
  }
}
```

Right now i have implemented this "old fashion" way. Model and id are saved in product view using hidden input fields, but this feels redundant.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Instead having to render {{ (product | async)?.model }} in my view to hidden input field, and then pass it on to addToCart() method using HTMLInputElement i would rather just pass qty, as for model and id i would like to access it directly from addToCart method by this.product.model

Comment: Still very unclear. But I guess you just want to subscribe to the observable from your component, to receive the next product from the observable.

Comment: Hmm i  have resolved this by changing private product : Observable<Product>; to private renderedProduct : Product; this.productService.product.subscribe(prod=>this.renderedProduct=prod); Anyhow seems like it was a mistake to have observable in component in the first place. Apologies for unclear question.